# Building path does not give me methods

Tags: java, apache

I've downloaded the apache math commons from the website and built the path for all the jars in the folder. I do not get an error when importing. But when I try to call a method, it says it doesn't exist and when looking through the library and clicking on the class I'm trying to call it says no source available. Why isn't building the path working and why can't I use the math library after building a path to it? I'm using eclipse

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.math3.*;
public class mathtest 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double[] can=new double[5];
    double[] bottle=new double[10];
    Arrays.fill(can, 1);
    Arrays.fill(bottle, 2);
    System.out.println(homoscedasticT(can,bottle));

}
}
```

Comment: I do not believe so, how do I do that?

Comment: I have and I still haven't been able to use any functions. I've imported all of the math classes and tried to performed this method: homoscedasticT(bin1counter,bin2counter); 
but instead I get an error that says "The method homoscedasticT() is undefined for the type SlideWindow"

Comment: Added an example that I wrote, still unable to use the math library even when all jar files from the download had been added to the reference library by building path

Comment: isn't `homoscedasticT` in `TTest` which is in `org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference`? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/TTest.html

In java there's no functions - only class methods. You should call it via it's class name:`new TTest().homoscedasticT(can, bottle)`

Comment: Yes, I seem to have been using it wrong. Thank you